# How can i get save metric per second on prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, prometheus, metrics

For **k8s v1.8** and **Prometheus v2.2.1**

*I want to know number of metrics per second stored by Prometheus*

How do I extract that information?

Comment: How do you want to know ? From Grafana ? From the Prometheus request language ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prometheus exposes the metric `prometheus_tsdb_head_samples_appended_total` in the `/metrics` path of your prometheus instance. This counter represents the `Total number of appended samples`.

You can then use if for computing the rate of ingestion:

```
rate(prometheus_tsdb_head_samples_appended_total[1m])
```

Which is effectively the number of metrics per second stored by Prometheus as taken from the last minute.

If you want to sample the instantaneous number of metrics per second, you can also use [irate()](https://www.robustperception.io/irate-graphs-are-better-graphs) instead.